# Unable to rename existing edge relationships; Using UNSAFE fails

Tags: orientdb

I cannot seem to rename an Edge. Is this possible with OrientDB?

I am running OrientDB in distributed mode on 3 servers.
Each server is configured as

- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
- OrientDB: 3.0.9

In the Studio web interface, To rename an Edge, I click the "rename" button adjacent to the Edge I want to rename.

I get this message at the bottom of the screen:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Cannot alter class 'Transfer2' because is an Edge class and could break vertices. Use UNSAFE if you want to force it DB name="marksluser"
```

In the console, I execute

```
orientdb {db=marksluser}> ALTER CLASS Transfer2 NAME Transfer UNSAFE;

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Invalid class name: ALTER CLASS Transfer2 NAME Transfer UNSAFE
DB name="marksluser"
DB name="marksluser"

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Cannot alter class 'Transfer2' because is an Edge class and could break vertices. Use UNSAFE if you want to force it
DB name="marksluser"
```

I also tried to rename the in and out edges to the new name as described in  [Renaming existing edge relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236442/renaming-existing-edge-relationships) however it still didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like your first command didn't have UNSAFE in it while your second one had a wrong class name in it. Keep in mind the syntax should be "ALTER CLASS <class> <attribute-name> <attribute-value> UNSAFE"

Comment: I am trying to change the name of Edge class from "Transfer2" to "Transfer". In the GUI, there is no option to specify UNSAFE. Is "ALTER CLASS Transfer2 NAME Transfer UNSAFE" incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this again with a clean database running 3.0.9 and the issue remains. I tried it with the development version 3.1.0-M2 and using "UNSAFE" works!

Looks like I wil be working on the 3.1.0-M2 release.

So if you want to rename an edge from "Edge1" to "Edge2" and all your vertices are subclasses of V, execute:

```
ALTER CLASS Edge1 NAME Edge2 UNSAFE;
UPDATE V SET out_Edge2 = out_Edge1 where out_Edge1 is not null;
UPDATE V SET in_Edge2 = in_Edge1 where in_Edge1 is not null;
UPDATE V REMOVE out_Edge1 where out_Edge1 is not null;
UPDATE V REMOVE in_Edge1 where in_Edge1 is not null;
```